# How to convert database foxpro (.dbf) file to sqlite database file using PHP script?

Tags: php

I am trying to convert database foxpro (.dbf) file to sqlite database file using PHP scrpit.. Please help me to convert the dbf files to sqlite files or provide suggestion for conversion.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Check the [dbase](http://www.php.net/dbase)-function:

```
$dbf = @dbase_open('yourfile.dbf', 0) or die("Error opening file.");
$fields = dbase_get_header_info($dbf);

foreach($fields as $field) { //... }
```

Also have a look at the [example](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php#82405) on the manual-page, it covers your issue.